# Change repeat interval of PeriodicWorkRequest after it has been enqueued

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Is there any easy way how to change repeat interval of `PeriodicWorkRequest`?

Let's have a `Worker` which is triggered every 6 hours and already enqueued, but i need to change it to 3 hours period.

If the solution is cancel the request and create new one, what is the clean way without duplicate it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make period work unique, by using `WorkManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork`.
and use `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE` as policy.

refer: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#enqueueuniqueperiodicwork

note that workmanager version should be above or equal to 1.0.0-alpha03

Comment: That makes sense and as I noticed from changes to alpha03, they are really improving it constantly towards production version.